# Switch repository of Files in SVN

Tags: svn

I have copied some files from project A to project B, both of which are under version control with their own repositories. When I try to add the files from project A that are now in project B to B's repository, it tells me they have conflicting UUID's, and it's still considering the files as part of project A's repository. Is there a way to switch what repository the files are in so they are now considered part of project B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply delete your SVN folders from project A.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy files/folders from one SVN repository to another you need to copy them without all the .svn folders. I think that is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have copied *folders*? Because files shouldn't be a problem.

With folders, it's likely that you have `.svn` metadata in project B that belongs to project A.

I think you won't get around manually exporting all folders in project B that came from project A (thus, removing the faulty `.svn` directories), and re-add them. Too much risk of messing things up badly otherwise IMO. I did similar things when I started working with SVN - duplicated folders within the repository, producing totally freaky results with those folders not getting checked in at all. Cost me a day to sort out.

*Always* export when copying folders inside or across repositories.